# git "fatal: .git/index: index file open failed: Permission denied"

Tags: windows, git, github

So, I have been working on a project and have been using git to push to github, and then suddenly today after I have been working for a little while I went to `git add` and got `fatal: .git/index: index file open failed: Permission denied`

I can't think of anything I have done recently on my computer that would cause this. Although I woke up today noticing my computer had rebooted overnight, and I noticed some different settings were not how I normally leave them. For instance quiet mode was turned off, and I always have that on. Thought it was kind of weird but ran a virus scan and didn't notice anything so I shrugged it off thinking it may be something on window's end.

Should I be nervous something is playing with my permissions? After a few minutes of googling I haven't found out too much on this error. Kinda baffled because I haven't personally changed any permissions and it everything seemed fine yesterday.

Looking for some help, if there is anything else I need to include to solve this error I'll gladly provide it if asked. Nobody else uses this computer. It is a Windows 10 build, `git version 2.6.3.windows.1`.

edit: Here's the output

```
11:21:34.673917 trace.c:319             setup: git_dir: .git
11:21:34.674417 trace.c:320             setup: git_common_dir: .git
11:21:34.674417 trace.c:321             setup: worktree: D:/Downloads/AnotherTabExample
11:21:34.674417 trace.c:322             setup: cwd: D:/Downloads/AnotherTabExample
11:21:34.674417 trace.c:323             setup: prefix: (null)
11:21:34.674417 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'add' '.'
fatal: .git/index: index file open failed: Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of the following command : `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=1 git add`

Comment: @AshutoshJindal `'GIT_CURL_VERBOSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of the way you are executing the command? I can't figure out why you would see an error with the command. Here is an example, I just tried: http://i.imgur.com/iKuJaLi.png . Also besides the above command, can you please try executing `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=1 git status`

Comment: Didn't think to try it in MingW, my bad. I updated the question with the output since it was too long to post in a comment.

Comment: Cool, see my answer below. Would be great if you could please update your question with the output of `ls -al .git/index`

Comment: I had a similar problem out of the blue, perhaps from using Windows Subsystem for Linux and VSCode to access the git directory at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the verbose output, it appears that the permissions of the `.git/index` while might have gotten corrupted.

Confirm that this is the case by doing a `ls -al .git/index` followed by a `chmod 644 .git/index` to fix it. Then try running the `git add` command again.

#### Update

It turned out to be a (Windows) permissions issue. What worked was simply creating a copy **from within msysgit** of the original folder and using that (i.e. `cp -rvf original original-bkup`).

A reset of the permissions on the original folder should have worked, but didn't.

Comment: `$ ls -al .git/index
-rw-r--r-- 1 janedoe 197609 11054 Dec 15 05:46 .git/index`

`$ chmod 644 .git/index`

`$ git add .
fatal: .git/index: index file open failed: Permission denied`

Comment: do you still have the same problem after doing the `chmod` ?

Comment: Wanna discuss this in SO's chat? If so, please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98274/gitishness

Answer (score 28):

Mark: If you have this error in Android studio, just restart your android studio and this error will be solved. I guess that This is because of some 'cache' or 'bug' of intellij idea.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also worth pointing out this works in any Jetbrains IDE.

Comment: for visual studio also, no need to restart, just close the Visual Studio instance that is currently open on the same folder as the one you try to commit

Comment: in intelij idea too